# Erro ao chamar endpoint: Exception has occurred: CLR/System.NullReferenceException C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net, nullpointerexception

Galera, estou tentando gerar uma planilha preenchida com os dados que tenho do SQL server, consigo fazer o get dessas informações certo mas quando chamo um método responsável por pegar essas informações e gravar elas em uma planilha Excel sempre que o endpoint que contem esse método é chamado tomo erro de referência null(pelo menos é o que entendi).

Tentei debugar mas mesmo marcando no método responsável com breakpoint ele não chega nem a entrar pra eu poder entender melhor o que acontece lá dentro.

Existe algum outro jeito além do breakpoint pra pegar o que está causando esse erro  ?

> [image: Erro que tomo sempre que chama o endpoint]

Aqui tem o método que chamo na controller :

```
public class CriarExcel
{

    private readonly EmployeeRepository _repository;

    public CriarExcel(EmployeeRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
    public string PreencherExcel()
    {   
        try
        {
            ArquivoExcelEmployee arquivoExcelEmployee = new ArquivoExcelEmployee();

            Console.WriteLine("Carregando configurações...");
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json");
            var configuration = builder.Build();

            DateTime dataHoraExtracao = DateTime.Now;
            var excelConfigurations = new ExcelConfigurations();
            new ConfigureFromConfigurationOptions<ExcelConfigurations>(
                configuration.GetSection("ExcelConfigurations"))
                    .Configure(excelConfigurations);

            Console.WriteLine("Gerando o arquivo .xlsx (Excel) com as cotações...");

            string arquivoXlsx = arquivoExcelEmployee.GerarArquivo(
                excelConfigurations, dataHoraExtracao,
                _repository.Get());
            Console.WriteLine($"O arquivo {arquivoXlsx} foi gerado com sucesso!");

             return arquivoXlsx;

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
           throw Ex;
        }
       
        
    }

}
```

Comment: O erro indica que a variável _criarExcel é nula. Tem certeza que essa variável foi inicializada? Se puder colocar o código do controller também seria mais fácil de ajudar.

Comment: É exatamente isso o _criarExcel  , me falaram pra pesquisar sobre injeção de construtor e descobri que tinha que colocar esse _criarExcel  = criarExcel   e adicionar no startup.cs depois que fiz isso deu certinho.

Comment: private readonly CriarExcel _criarExcel;
        public EmployeeController(CriarExcel criarExcel )
        {
            
            _criarExcel = criarExcel //Por _criarExcel  não estar iniciada aprensentava o erro
        }

Comment: Obrigado @TallesSantana

Comment: Que bom que o meu comentário ajudou. De nada :)

Comment: @NicholasSouza só uma dica além do que já te disseram... Apague esse seu bloco try-catch, pois ele não está a fazer nada além de pesar mais o seu código. Essa instrução tem um custo elevado e nesse seu cenário não está fazendo nada. Um abraço!

Comment: Obrigado @PedroPaulo não sabia que tinha impacto na performance